# Can data be added to a file for better compression?

Tags: zip, compression

If I understand the basic idea of ZIP compression correctly (and I think compression in general), compressed files are just patterns found in the original data expressed in shorter notation. Are there compression algorithms out there that insert junk/unimportant data to a file to add patterns where there once were none? Is that violating some file integrity rule, or even just diminishing returns?

Mostly I was thinking of adding whitespace to something that doesn't care about it, like an HTML file.

EDIT: a more concrete example would probably be better:

```
.class-a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
.class-b {display:block;color:#fff;}
```

Obviously minification (and reusing classes) would be the best practice here, but this is a question for how an algorithm could do things, not humans. Would adding any amount of whitespace to have the latter line match the former provide any use whatsoever?

EDITEDIT: This all sounds like some bizarre parody of lossy compression, now that I think about it. Gainy compression or some nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in principle adding more information to the file will increase the amount of information that must be included in the compressed file too, so the compressed file will be larger.

If there is the string AAA in a file, and if a repetition of that pattern is added, then the compressed file will have to include a representation of AAA *plus* something to say that the pattern is repeated elsewhere. Recording where the pattern is repeated takes up space too.

Another way of looking at it, using the HTML example, would be that if you add lots of whitespace, then that will probably compress well, so the final size of the compressed file will at best stay the same. So the "compression ratio" would be higher, but there also wouldn't be any more interesting content in the uncompressed file, so the absolute improvement in compression would be at best zero.